# how extract data from huge csv file to php?

Tags: php, csv

I have a very long csv file with tens of columns and thousands of rows. I need to fetch info on specific data only from that csv using php.

The csv file is at: http://www.ezmedia2u.com/software/hworiginal.csv .

The data sample that I want to get is from line 1203 to line 1275, 'entire page', and I need to display that in table format.

Comment: Can you use a database?

Comment: Im with @Passerby import the csv file into a database and then you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch data from csv file try this.

```
<?php
     $fp = fopen('test.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
     print "<table>\n";
     while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
       print '<tr>';
       for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
         print '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';
       }
       print "</tr>\n";
     }
     print '</table>\n';
     fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
?>
```